# Python with open and pd.to_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I wanted to clarify that the following code below opens an existing CSV file with the name `fn`, clears all the existing data in the CSV file and essentially writes the new data in an empty CSV file?

```
  # Assume df is pre-defined pandas DataFrame filled with data
  with open(fn, 'wb') as csvfile:
       df.to_csv(csvfile, index=True, header=True)
```

If not, how can I clear all data in the existing CSV file without `os.delete(fn)`, then creating a new CSV file?

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: `wb` opens the file in write and binary modes. It will overwrite it if exists and make a new file. You would have to use `a+` to open the file in append mode.

Comment: The following would also work: `df.to_csv(fn, index=True, header=True)`. If you want to use some sort of encoding you can specify this with the `encoding="ascii"` or another.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
fn = open("file.csv", "r+")
f.seek(0)
f.truncate()
```

Comment: opening the file in write mode (`'w'`) is the [recommended way](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to do what the OP is asking for